# Cannot save changes to config file in /etc/kbd/config

Tags: raspbian, linux

I am attempting to disable text and screen blanking in my Raspberry Pi but I cannot save the changes as it says "Can't open file to write". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Open the file with root access using sudo. To open it with Nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/kbd/config
```

You need root permission because the file is owned by root, not the pi user. You can learn more about sudo (which stands for *super user do*) by entering `man sudo` which will open the manual page (help documentation) for the sudo command. Most commands will have a man page, for instance try `man man`.